# How to 'Check if there are duplicate values on POST Array'?

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I have a page wherein the user can choose between checkbox items. My concern is that anyone can edit those checkbox values using developer mode. I am thinking that after clicking submit, a php page will verify if there are repeating values from the POST array.

Values of each checkbox items have the same length. So I cannot just simply compare the length of each element inside the $_POST['arr1'].

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="arr1[]" value="201468"> One<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="arr1[]" value="201469" > Two <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="arr1[]" value="201470" > Three <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On the action page

I have no idea what to put here to check if arr1[] would have duplicate values.

Comment: make an array of your actuall value in php side and then when you get value form user check through the php array like if(in_array($userValue,$phpArray))

Comment: `array_unique`, `array_count_values`, compare POST against other array with values.

Comment: why don't you add unique values in the value attribute? so no need to check in PHP duplicates

Comment: I have unique values. It is just that any user can edit values through developer mode on browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! Turns out that "array_unique" is the solution I have been looking for.